# Не могу настроить router (php, open server)

Tags: php, nginx, apache, сервер, openserver

Создал в корне проекта файл .htaccess в который копировал конфигурацию сервера(nginx, apache) - не помогло. (соответственно менял и в open server)
Пробовал переместить .htaccess в /public/ - тоже ничего не происходит
Перемещал index.php в корень проекта - те же пироги.

При попытке передать любое значение/строку выдает 404

["REQUEST_URI"]=> "/project_name/public/another_string

["SCRIPT_NAME"]=> "/project_name/public/index.php"

Comment: казалось бы логично указать корень домена в настройках опенсервера как projectname/public, Тогда очевидно, uri  project/public/index.php приведет к 404, а запрашивать надо просто index.php.
не известно правда, что там у вас в этом хтаксессе написано.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо). Подправил файл .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Корень домена сменил и заработало)
Запускал через IDE файл index.php а не сам проект (openserver/мои проекты/another_project) что и привело к некорректной работе.